# HTML 5 video tag on my site, is not working on mobile devices

Tags: html

I have a video tag on my website. When I check on desktop devices it is showing the default video first frame, but when I check on mobile devices such as ios the default frame is not shown.it comes blank but the video is present.
I want the first video frame to be shown

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Bro , for mobile devices the video cannot play automatically as in desktop, You have to set the play button to play the video. If you want to play a video automatically means you can use GIF. It will play automatically